# Извлечение данных, представленных в формате XML, из MySQL - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, xml, blob

Доброго времени суток!

Есть БД MySQL, расположенная на сервере. В одной из таблиц БД представлены данные в формате blob (бинарное представление xml). Мне нужно вычленить эти данные и представить пользователю, выведя их в richtextbox.

Сразу говорю, что с xml никогда работать не приходилось, а решить эту задачу нужно вот прям сейчас.

Был наивный вариант вывести все как обычное значение, но он оказался бесполезным:

```
static string connectionString = "тут путь до сервера";
static MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

string query = "SELECT ReqData, AnsData FROM tab_482 WHERE Npp = 545"  ;

connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

richTextBox1.Text = reader["ReqData"].ToString();
richTextBox2.Text = reader["AnsData"].ToString();

reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

После посещения нескольких сайтов стало понятно, что нужно использовать специальный reader для xml, но в тех примерах ссылаются сразу на файл, а как указать путь к ячейке таблицы через SQl запрос...

Был еще такой вариант:

```
byte[] barray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(((reader["ReqData"]).ToString()).ToCharArray());
            string str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(barray);
richTextBox1.Text = str;
```

но в обоих случаях выводится только `System.byte[]`.

Подскажите, как все-таки забрать данные из БД, чтобы пользователь увидел xml код?

Comment: Во втором варианте не нужен `ToString()` и `ToCharArray()`

Comment: Попробуйте что-то вроде `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(reader["ReqData"])`

Comment: Чтобы получить байты из ридера, попробуйте его кастовать к байтам `var reqBytes = (byte[] reader["ReqData"];)`

Comment: [How to manually decode an ActiveSync WBXML stream](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2013/02/04/how-to-manually-decode-an-activesync-wbxml-stream/)

Comment: @АндрейNOP `reader["ReqData"]` имеет тип `object`, поэтому компилятор ругается, что не может `object` в `byte[]` перегнать

Comment: Ну тогда `richTextBox1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString((byte[])reader["ReqData"])`

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, помогло. Спасибо большое... всё оказалось как всегда просто

Comment: Напишите ответом как у вас получилось, пригодится для будущих спрашивающих

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодарю всех за помощь. В результате у меня получилось следующее:

```
richTextBox1.Text = Encoding.Default.GetString((byte[])reader["ReqData"]);
```

В этом случае все данные выводятся в одну строку.

Чтобы интерпретировать в более читабельный вариант (при условии, что в БД хранится валидный xml), следует загрузить его в `XDocument` и воспользоваться методом `ToString()`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString((byte[])reader["ReqData"]));
richTextBox1.Text = xdoc.ToString();
```